# How to store website user information sharing my page over google+?

Tags: javascript, google-plus, sharing

I want to store user information like username, share url , share date, status(shared or cancelled) etc in a separate table in my DB. But I do not find a way to do this. How ever I can do what I want with Facebook sharing using `FB.ui()` method.

I know there are data-onendinteraction data-onstartinteraction, but how could I know If the User cancelled or Shared the url. More over I just the google+ share dialog button to be opened on "click" not on "hover" action.

Answer (score 0):

Google+ doesn't provide details of who is sharing your information. It's a violation of their privacy. Your best bet would be to track the times at which G+ shares are taken and try to match that with public results in [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search).